# Mobile application Android

Tags: android

Give your buttons some behavior.
change the foreground color of the Button that was clicked. Choose at random
among Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, etc. To change the color of the
Button, call setTextColor on the Button that is passed to the event handler. However, note
that although Button has a setTextColor method, View (the parent class of Button) does
not. So, you have to cast the View to Button before calling setTextColor.

Comment: What you want to ask ??

Comment: Button greetingButton = new Button(this);
        greetingButton.setText(buttonLabel1);
        greetingButton.setOnClickListener(new Toaster());
        mainWindow.addView(greetingButton);
        greetingButton.setTextColor(Color.RED); // change the foreground color of the Button that was clicked( I would like to get a random color)
        setContentView(mainWindow);

Answer (score 0):

cast your view by button and find its Id by using findview_by_id , then set the color...

(Button)view.findviewbyid(R.id.btn_id).setTextColor();

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_stack);
  mainView=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);
  final Button redButton=new Button(this);
  redButton.setText("Click");
  redButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
  redButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    redButton.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
   }
  });
  mainView.addView(redButton);
 }
```

Comment: Could u please edit on my code coz i tried to cast it but it didn't work      Button greetingButton = new Button(this);
        greetingButton.setText(buttonLabel1);
        greetingButton.setOnClickListener(new Toaster());
        mainWindow.addView(greetingButton);
        greetingButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        setContentView(mainWindow);

Comment: I don't think the way you initialize the greenButton would work as you are trying to parse 'this' as a button (assuming you are on activitys' onCreate method). You should be able to get it work if you do what @logan has described.